# How many paths in a $n\times m$ grid which is not crossing the diagonal.

Tags: combinatorics

I want to make a generalization of Catalan numbers, so I make an $n\times m$ (where $n$ and $m$ are coprime) grid and try to find a number of paths which is not crossing the diagonal.

I think it will be ${2\over n+m} \binom{m+n}{n}$, but I can't find proof of it.

Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** First, count the number of paths which stay *above* the diagonal, then multiply by $2$.

Write a path as a sequence of $n+m$ steps which are all either $\def\U{\mathsf U}\U$ (for "up") or $\def\R{\mathsf R}\R$ (for "right"). Define the cyclic shift of a path by $k$ places to be the result of removing a block of of $k$ symbols from the beginning and adding them to the end in the same order. 
$$
 \underline{\U\R\R}\U\R\U\U\U\R\implies\U\R\U\U\U\R \underline{\U\R\R}\tag{cyclic shift by 3}
$$
Show that among all $m+n$ possible cyclic shifts of a path, exactly one of them will stay above the diagonal. In particular, considering a path as a sequence of points $(x_i,y_i)$, and letting $k$ be the index for which $mx_k-ny_k$ is minimized, then the cyclic shift by $k$ places will be the unique shift which makes the path stay above the diagonal.